# Visual Studio 2012 Express - Images don't get compiled/copied

Tags: c++

maybe someone here can help me. I'm an amateur programmer having experience mostly in C#.

I started looking into C++ more the last few days and have run into a problem that I can't figure out. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop.

Whenever I add resources, such as images (jpg, png, bmp) to my solution through the solution explorer, they don't get copied into the solution folder on the harddrive. What's even more of a problem is the fact that these images don't get copied/compiled when I compile my project!! As such, the program fails to run. If I manually copy the files to the, in this case, Debug folder, everything works fine. I set the "Content" property in the file properties to True as well as the "Add to project" property.

I can't figure this out for the life of it. :( In MS Visual Studio 2010 Express C# it always worked. Is there something I'm missing in the new version?

Btw, sorry if some of this doesn't make any sense. English is not my native tongue and I'm using Visual Studio in German.

Hope someone can give me an answer!

Best regards,

Michael

Answer (score 2):

In the solution explorer right-click the files and choose "Properties". Then change "Copy to output directory" to "Always". Possibly also change "Build Action" to "Content".

Comment: Hey Vilx, thanks for your reply. Thats what I remember from VS 2010 as well. And that's what I've tried here. But when I open the "properties" for the file as you said, I only have three options/setting. "Exclude from Build: Yes/No", "Content: Yes/No", and "Element Type: <various settings>". Exlude from Build is set to No, Content is set to Yes, and Element Type is automatically set to image. Hope that makes sense. Like I said I'm using the German version and trying to translate this.

Comment: Be sure you do it like explained at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bka19x4.aspx: To add an existing resource
    With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu, click Properties.
    Select the Resources tab.
    On the Resource Designer toolbar, point to Add Resource, click the arrow, and then click Add Existing File.
    In the Add existing file to resources dialog box, browse to the file that contains the resource that you want to add (.bmp, .ico, .wav, etc,), and then click Open...

Comment: @Michael: Oh... ok then. Then I'm out of ideas. :P

Comment: @duDE - Those are **resources** which are compiled in the .exe (or .dll) file and are something completely different than what the OP wants (namely, copying a certain file to output directory).

Comment: I think not sice he wrote "they don't get copied into the solution folder on the harddrive", "As such, the program fails to run."  - or what do you exactly mean, Michael?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your time. 
@duDE - Thanks for the link, but like Vilx said, thats not exactly what I meant. Adding a resource so that it gets compiled into the .exe was not my intention. But EVEN if I wanted to do that, I'm too retarded to do it! I looked at your link. From what I was able to google that window should look something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rKybL.png correct? When I open it on my computer the resource tab is not there! It goes straight from Manifest Tool to XML Document Generator. :( I must be doing something majorly wrong here.

Comment: @duDe - And just to clarify my previous statement. What I meant was the following. Back in VS 2010, when I added an existing resource to my project (no matter if the file was saved on the desktop or wherever) it was automatically copied into the projects folder on my harddrive (in my case \Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\<project folder>. Then, when I compiled it, the necessary resources (images, sound files, etc.) were of course also copied/compiled into the Debug/Release folder. 
With VS 2012 neither thing is happening.

Comment: Ah, I have an idea: do you have started with console project? Try it with Win32 or MFC please ... Close Project -> New Project -> MFC. Do you have the Tab now?

Comment: Hey again. I created an empty project actually. I just now created a new one for the purpose of testing. No matter what I choose, Empty Project or Win32 Project, the Resource Tab is there! But once I add my existing .h and .cpp files, the tab disappears.

Comment: I just thought, maybe it's something in my current code. So I created a new project -> resource tab is there. I add a new empty header file -> resource tab disappears. Weird?

Comment: @Michael - Not weird. You need a resource file (.rc) in your project to work with resources. Unfortunately the Express editions do not include a resource editor, so you cannot make one with it. However it is a plain text file and you could theoretically make it by hand, if you followed the strict syntax. I also think there are 3rd party resource editors out there, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Michael - Anyways, this is not what you want, although it might be a nice way to package your program.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in my C++ Projects in Visual Studio 2013. I wasn't able to find a "copy if newer" or "copy always" option. If there is one in C++ let me know.

For a work around, i edited the [Projectname].vcxproj file.

Look for a line like this:

```
<None Include="./yourcontentfile.dll" />
```

or

```
<Content Include="./yourcontentfile.dll" />
```

Change that line to the following:

```
<None Include="./yourcontentfile.dll">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

or

```
<Content Include="./yourcontentfile.dll">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

This will copy that file to the output directory when you build.